# JTextPane Word Wrapper

Tags: java, swing

Não estou encontrando um metodo para organizar as linhas dentro de um JTextPane, sendo que preciso continuar com as estilizações mas também com um Word Wrapper, há algum metodo ou algum componente que faça parecido?

```
public class PanelTeste extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public PanelTeste() {
        initComponents();
        initTeste();
    }

    public void initTeste() {

        //"panel" é o JTextPane
        scroll.setViewportView(panel);
        scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        StyledDocument doc = panel.getStyledDocument();

        SimpleAttributeSet keyWord = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        StyleConstants.setForeground(keyWord, Color.RED);
        StyleConstants.setBackground(keyWord, Color.YELLOW);
        StyleConstants.setBold(keyWord, true);

        try {
            doc.insertString(0, "Algo aqui", keyWord);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        scroll = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        panel = new javax.swing.JTextPane();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        scroll.setViewportView(panel);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                .addComponent(scroll, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 197, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(19, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(31, 31, 31)
                .addComponent(scroll, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 156, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PanelTeste.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PanelTeste.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PanelTeste.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PanelTeste.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new PanelTeste().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextPane panel;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane scroll;
    // End of variables declaration                   

}
```

Comment: O que é word wrapper? O que você já fez até agora? Adicione um [mcve] para que seja possível testar o problema.

Comment: Word Wrapper seria para quebrar de linha tipo no final do campo escrever uma palavra grande ele mandar para baixo em vez de cortar ela pela metade. No JTextArea da para fazer, sem problemas. Postado o que já tenho.

Comment: Não existe esse método no JTextPane, somente na textarea.

Comment: Sim. Acabei de conseguir na internet umas classes que fazem isso de forma "forçada", eu edito a pergunta, respondo ela mesmo, como faço para deixar o link para quem possívelmente queira usar?

Comment: Pode responder a sua pergunta no campo abaixo e marcar como aceita.

Comment: Isso aqui funcionou pra mim: https://www.java-forums.org/awt-swing/59790-line-wrapping-jtextpane.html#post286197

Comment: Esse não deu certo comigo. Enfim, postado o que funcionou para mim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui encontrar um link em que é criada algumas classes com suas devidas extensões e adicionada ao `JTextPane`.

**As classes a serem criadas são as seguintes**

```
class WrapEditorKit extends StyledEditorKit {
    ViewFactory defaultFactory=new WrapColumnFactory();
    public ViewFactory getViewFactory() {
        return defaultFactory;
    }

}

class WrapColumnFactory implements ViewFactory {
    public View create(Element elem) {
        String kind = elem.getName();
        if (kind != null) {
            if (kind.equals(AbstractDocument.ContentElementName)) {
                return new WrapLabelView(elem);
            } else if (kind.equals(AbstractDocument.ParagraphElementName)) {
                return new ParagraphView(elem);
            } else if (kind.equals(AbstractDocument.SectionElementName)) {
                return new BoxView(elem, View.Y_AXIS);
            } else if (kind.equals(StyleConstants.ComponentElementName)) {
                return new ComponentView(elem);
            } else if (kind.equals(StyleConstants.IconElementName)) {
                return new IconView(elem);
            }
        }

        // default to text display
        return new LabelView(elem);
    }
}

class WrapLabelView extends LabelView {
    public WrapLabelView(Element elem) {
        super(elem);
    }

    public float getMinimumSpan(int axis) {
        switch (axis) {
            case View.X_AXIS:
                return 0;
            case View.Y_AXIS:
                return super.getMinimumSpan(axis);
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid axis: " + axis);
        }
    }

}
```

Após isso, deve se usar o seguinte metodo do JTextPane.
`seuJTextPanel.setEditorKit(new WrapEditorKit());`

Assim sendo possível fazer com que quando a palavra seja muito grande, ela passe para linha de baixo.

**Referencia**
[Fix for wrap](http://java-sl.com/tip_letter_wrap_java7.html)

Comment: Mas você não apresentou como solucionou na resposta. Procure deixar a solução aqui, para que não seja dependente de link externo.  E não existe WrapEditorKit na api do java.

Comment: Desculpe, não estou acostumado a responder as perguntas. Obrigado pelo aviso. Editado.